# How to automatically add a space between the close parenthesis and the open curly brace in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

is it possible to automatically add a white space between the close parenthesis and the open curly brace in function definitions, loops, if...
In Eclipse that was automatic when pressing enter after typing the curly brace. I looked in Settings > Code Style but didn't find anything useful.